# When using devise in rails, how do I add two different types of users that will use the site in two different ways?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, devise

I'm building a job board application. I'm new to programming and am teaching myself the rails framework.

I'm using Devise for authentication. I will have two different types of users; `Job Seeker` and `Employer`. The job seeker will create a profile and search for job postings and the employer will create a company profile and post job listings. In the future, the employer will also be able to search for employees based on qualifications, experience, education, etc. but for now I'm just building my MVP.

Comment: Try to use this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-a-default-role-to-a-User. I hope this help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This type of functionality is tricky, namely because you have to put functionality before implementation (IE most people get hung up about `Devise`, whereas it might not feature at all)

---

You have two ways:

> - [**Roles**](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) (authorization)
> - [**Multiple models**](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-multiple-models) (authentication)

Devise is an *authentication* system (user logged in); you may be better using *authorization* (can user do x or y). Authorization is out of Devise's scope.

Whilst you could use multiple models (Devise), I think it creates too much unnecessary bloat for what you need.

Instead, I would use a *very* simple role system (using [`enum`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)):

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   enum role: [:job_seeker, :employer]

   has_one :profile
   before_create :build_profile

   has_many :applications
   has_many :listings, through: :applications
end

#app/models/application.rb
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :listing
    belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/listing.rb
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :applications
   has_many :applicants, through: :applications, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :user_id
end
```

You'll need to add a `role` column (`int`) to your `users` table. You'll create the *default* role by using a `default: [x]` switch when creating your column:

```
def change
   add_column :users, :role, :integer, default: 0 #-> defaults to job seeker
end
```

--

You've described several factors which would lend themselves perfectly to this:

> - `Job seeker` will create a profile
> - `Employer` will create a profile and post listings

... all meaning your ["flow"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(software)) will remain similar for both user types. You'd just have to manage what each user can do with authorization.

---

## Setup

```
#config/routes.rb
resource  :profile, controller: :users, only: [:show, :update] #-> url.com/profile
resources :listings, only: [:show] do
   post :apply, on: :member #-> url.com/listings/:id/apply
end
resources :companies, controller: :users, only: [:show]

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   #show will automatically be loaded

   def update
      current_user.update profile_params
   end

   private

   def profile_params
      params.require(:user).permit(profile_attributes: [:name, :etc, :etc])
   end
end

#app/views/users/show.html.erb
<%= form_for current_user do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :profile do |p| 
      <% if current_user.job_seeker? %>
         <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Your name" %>
      <% elsif current_user.employer? %>
         <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Company name" %>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

You'd then be able to use the following to check whether a user can *create* listings, or just view:

```
#app/controllers/listings_controller.rb
class ListingsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :check_seeker, only: [:apply]
   before_action :check_employer, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

   def new  #-> employers
      @listing = current_user.listings.new
   end

   def apply #-> job seekers
      @listing     = Listing.find params[:id]
      @application = current_user.applications.new
      @application.listing = @listing
      redirect_to @listing, notice: "Application successful!" if @application.save 
   end

   private

   def check_seeker
      redirect_to listings_path, notice: "Only Job Seekers Allowed" unless current_user.job_seeker?
   end

   def check_employer
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Only Employers Allowed" unless current_user.employer?
   end
end
```

Hopefully this gives you the gist.

---

## Devise

To get Devise working with your new column, you'll need to [extend the Devise Sanitizer](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters):

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :role
  end
end
```

This will allow you to change the `role` field on signup:

```
#app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb
.....
  <%= f.select :role, User.roles %>
```

Comment: Rich, your comment is tremendously appreciated. There is a lot of excellent information in here that will definitely assist me in building my app. Thank you for taking the type to explain and provide examples to your explanations! Definitely Appreciated!

Comment: Rich, how would I use this with Devise. I added the role migration. In my header for my app, the user has a drop down menu called 'Register' with two fields, Job Seeker and Employer. This would be where they'd make the selection so I wouldn't have a default. How would I modify your code to match this preference?

Comment: The user model has a `role_id` attribute or not?

Comment: Does not. I just found the documentation in Devise's Wiki that I believe might help me do this. I just have to rollback my migration that I've already made.

Comment: Okay if you do the rollback, let me know if it works; if it doesn't I'll help you out on here

Comment: Rich, I did the rollback but it didn't work so I did the 'rake db:migrate' command. I edited the role migration in the schema to be role_id: references (as described in the devise wiki). I performed a rake test after and I'm getting this error, ') Error:
PagesControllerTest#test_should_get_home:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2016-01-03 11:57:56', '2016-01-03 11:57:56', 298486374)' I have no idea where this is at?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to input into the db without an email. I presume the uniqueness validation expects one -- just add an email to your test

Comment: I just rebuilt my app, this was the first steps I was making anyway. I've went through the devise wiki and followed along with their code. My question now is, how do I associate the role_id with the selection the user makes on the UI?

Answer (score 2):

Devise is good for authentication but for role and access control you may want to look into Rolify: https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify.

This will allow you to keep a single user model and control access to different features with Role queries, ie:

```
unless current_user.has_role?(:admin)
  redirect_to ...
else
  render ...
end
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the recommendation. That will simplify things for me tremendously. Does rolify provide authentication or would I use Rolify with Devise?

Comment: You would use rolify and devise. you can also use Rolify with other auth frameworks but I have successfully used it with devise and was pretty happy with the result.

Answer (score 1):

For roles you can use `CanCanCan` gem and `RoleModel` gem with `devise` which will be better for user with different roles.

[CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan)

[Defining abilities using cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities)

[Role model gem](https://github.com/martinrehfeld/role_model)

[Example for user roles with above gems..](https://www.phase2technology.com/blog/authentication-permissions-and-roles-in-rails-with-devise-cancan-and-role-model/)